monaco-editor registerCompletionItemProvider custom
I need use monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider create a selection component for filter,for example element-ui el-select attribute:filter？
I need custom CompletionItemProvider by html. how do it? how use CompletionItemProvider
For example this image:

my code problem is I can't custom CompletionItemProvider  replace first monaco-list-row dom to <input />
filterable by input.
my code is this:
// vue code
 mounted() {
    const allSuggestions = [
      {
        label: 'Function 1',
        kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
        insertText: 'function1()',
        detail: 'Detail A',
        documentation: 'Description A'
      },
      {
        label: 'Function 2',
        kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
        insertText: 'function2()',
        detail: 'Detail B',
        documentation: 'Description B'
      },
      {
        label: 'Function 3',
        kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
        insertText: 'function3()',
        detail: 'Detail C',
        documentation: 'Description C'
      }
    ];
    monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('javascript', {
      provideCompletionItems: function () {
        return {
          suggestions: allSuggestions
        };
      }
    });
    this.editor = monaco.editor.create(this.$refs?.monacoContainer, {
        minimap: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        language: 'javascript',
        folding: true,
        lineDecorationsWidth: 35,
        wordWrap: 'on',
        theme: 'vs',
        fontLigatures: true,
        renderWhitespace: 'none',
        automaticLayout: true,
      });
    // use MutationObserver listen DOM change
        this.observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
          const suggestWidget = document.querySelector('.suggest-widget');
          if (suggestWidget && !suggestWidget.classList.contains('customized')) {
            suggestWidget.classList.add('customized');
            this.addFilterInputToSuggestWidget(suggestWidget);
          }
        });
    
        // observer DOM change
        const editorContainer = document.querySelector('.monaco-editor');
        if (editorContainer) {
          this.observer.observe(editorContainer, { childList: true, subtree: true });
        }
        // add CSS
        const style = document.createElement('style');
        style.textContent = `
          .suggest-filter-input {
            width: calc(100% - 20px);
            // margin: 5px;
            // padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
          }
          .customized {
          }
        `;
        document.head.appendChild(style);
},
 methods: {
    // add input
    addFilterInputToSuggestWidget(suggestWidget) {
      const listElement = suggestWidget.querySelector('.monaco-list');
      if (listElement) {
        if (listElement.querySelector('.suggest-filter-input')) return;

        const filterInput = document.createElement('input');
        filterInput.type = 'text';
        filterInput.placeholder = 'Type to filter suggestions...';
        filterInput.classList.add('suggest-filter-input');

        const firstRow = listElement.firstChild;
        listElement.insertBefore(filterInput, firstRow);

        filterInput.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
          const filterText = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
          this.updateFilteredSuggestions(filterText, suggestWidget);
        });

        filterInput.focus();
      }
    },
    updateFilteredSuggestions(filterText, suggestWidget) {
      this.resetSuggestions(suggestWidget);

      this.filterSuggestions(filterText, suggestWidget);
    },
    filterSuggestions(filterText, suggestWidget) {
      const rows = suggestWidget.querySelectorAll('.monaco-list-row');
      rows.forEach((row) => {
        const label = row.querySelector('.label-name');
        if (label) {
          const text = label.textContent.toLowerCase();
          if (!text.includes(filterText)) {
            row.remove();
          }
        }
      });
    },
    resetSuggestions(suggestWidget) {
      const listElement = suggestWidget.querySelector('.monaco-list');
      if (!listElement) return;

      const existingRows = listElement.querySelectorAll('.monaco-list-row');
      existingRows.forEach((row) => row.remove());

      const allSuggestions = [
        {
          label: 'Function 1',
          kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
          insertText: 'function1()',
          detail: 'Detail A',
          documentation: 'Description A',
        },
        {
          label: 'Function 2',
          kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
          insertText: 'function2()',
          detail: 'Detail B',
          documentation: 'Description B',
        },
        {
          label: 'Function 3',
          kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
          insertText: 'function3()',
          detail: 'Detail C',
          documentation: 'Description C',
        },
      ];

      allSuggestions.forEach((suggestion) => {
        const row = this.createSuggestionRow(suggestion);
        listElement.appendChild(row);
      });
    },
    createSuggestionRow(suggestion) {
      const row = document.createElement('div');
      row.classList.add('monaco-list-row');

      const label = document.createElement('span');
      label.classList.add('label-name');
      label.textContent = suggestion.label;

      const detail = document.createElement('span');
      detail.classList.add('label-detail');
      detail.textContent = suggestion.detail;

      row.appendChild(label);
      row.appendChild(detail);

      return row;
    },
 
  },

